# Python subprocess.check_output with ± characters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using a `subprocess.check_output` call to a MS DOS command line application to return the `stdout` string from the application.

The return from the check_ouput is information about the command just run, a new line containing the result I'm after and another new line. Specifically the return string looks like this:

```
b'0ms: Channel.#0.Range.SelectedItem?\r\n\xf150 mV\r\n'
```

The problem is the \xf1 after the first newline, that character is meant to be a ± (\xb1) but is always returned as a ñ (\xf1) and I can't work out why.

If I run the command manually in the command line I get the ± as I would expect so I don't think the command line application is at fault.

In the short term I can just replace any \xf1 I find with \xb1 but its a hack and I would prefer to prevent it rather than work around it.

Anyone got any ideas about why the character difference between command line and python?

Answer (score 2):

MS DOS aplications use a different character encoding than Windows Latin (cp1252) or the civilized world (web + unix: utf-8) -- for backwards compatibility purposes, they use CP850 code page.

All you have to do to have a proper Python unicode from this string is to decode it with the CP850 encoding, like in:

```
>>> print '0ms: Channel.#0.Range.SelectedItem?\r\n\xf150 mV\r\n'.decode("cp850")
0ms: Channel.#0.Range.SelectedItem?
±50 mV
```

Comment: Thats the encoding I was looking for, I'd tried a bunch of them with decode and none actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the program you are running outputs with another encoding than the one you are using in your python script. If I am right, and you find out which encoding it is, you can use `.decode(<origin-encoding>)` and `.encode(<target-encoding>)` methods to circumvent the process.

**Edit:** It seems I found a candidate encoding:

```
>>> print s.decode('cp850')
0ms: Channel.#0.Range.SelectedItem?
±50 mV
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee it is the right one for all possible outputs, just that it *might* be, and that it works for the `±` character...

**Edit2:** While I was fooling around with codecs, jsbueno came to the same conclusion, but with an "historical perspective" as to the why this codec could be the one you need to use...

HTH!

Comment: Yes, cp850 does the trick, I was just wasn't using the right encoding.